# Issue with Weighted Raster Overlay Service for Suitability Modeler Widget

Tags: arcgis-pro, web-service, widget, weighted-overlay, suitability-analysis

I'm attempting to build a hosted Weighted Raster Overlay Service (WRO) in ArcGISPro to use in AWAB's Suitability Modeler Widget. I've downloaded the Weighted Raster Overlay Service toolbox via [THIS](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/geoplanner/documentation/use-your-data-in-weighted-overlay.htm) source and prepared raster layers as described in the documentation (same cell size/integer/LZW compression etc). I'm running the "Create Weighted Overlay Mosaic" tool from the toolbox on 10 input GeoTIFFs from a folder, in order to create a Mosaic Dataset. The rasters in TOC are either individual integers representing a given theme, or grouped into classes via "Symbology" tab in ArcGIS Pro. Every time I run the tool it seem to complete with warnings, which seem to prevent me from going through the next steps of sharing the mosaic as a WRO Service. For each layer, I'm getting the following warnings:

- "Removed extension tif from LAYER 1,2,3,......"
- "Adding rasters to the mosaic
  LAYER1.tif is missing layer data.
  LAYER1.tif will not be inserted into the mosaic."

This is repeated for all of my input layers. The rasters are present in the Mosaic Dataset, however I'm not able to run either of the two other tools ("Update WRO Layer Classification"/"Update WRO Layer Info") as the tool does not recognise the input mosaic as a valid dataset (Error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'label_list' referenced before assignment). Consequently I cannot publish the mosaic to a WRO Service.

Has anyone come across this issue before? I was not able to find any reference regarding these errors and hoping someone may be able to offer some advice here.